# Proving that a subset is a subspace by showing a scalar combination.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> **Prove that:**
>
> $$S = \left\{\left(\begin{matrix}a & b \\ c & a\end{matrix}\right) \ /
>  \ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\right\} \subset M(2,\mathbb{R})$$
>
> ---
>
> **Answer:**
>
> $S$ is a scalar combination of $\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 &
>  1\end{matrix}\right) , \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 &
>  0\end{matrix}\right) , \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 &
>  0\end{matrix}\right)$

I'm guessing that by "scalar combination" they mean "linear combination". Anyway, I still don't quite understand this proof. Can you better explain this?

Comment: You can prove that a subset of a vector space is a subspace if for any scalar c the linear combination cx + y is still in the subset.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds clumsy me (although maybe I don't have the context here).

- $S$ should be described as the *span* of these matrices, or the *set of linear combinations* (maybe this is what is meant by "scalar combination", but it still should be "the set of...").

\begin{align*}
S &= \mathrm{span}\left\{\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 &
 1\end{matrix}\right) , \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 &
 0\end{matrix}\right) , \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 &
 0\end{matrix}\right)\right\} \\
&=\left\{a\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 &
 1\end{matrix}\right)+b \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 &
 0\end{matrix}\right)+c \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 &
 0\end{matrix}\right):a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\right\}
\\
\end{align*}

- Is the question asking to prove that $S$ is a subset of $M(2,\mathbb{R})$?  Then that's immediately true from the definition.  Probably there's something about confirming that $S$ is a subspace "offstage" here.

Answer (score 1):

The criteria a subset $S$ of a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ must satisfy to be a subspace (other than that $0 \in S$) are that $v + w \in S$ if $v, w \in S$ and $av \in S$ if $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $v \in S$. Since the given $S$ is spanned by 3 vectors $b_1, b_2, b_3$, it fulfills these criteria as $v + w = (c_1 b_1 + c_2 b_2 + c_3 b_3) + (d_1 b_1 + d_2 b_2 + d_3 b_3) = (c_1 + d_1)b_1 + (c_2 + d_2)b_2 + (c_3 + d_3)b_3 \in S$ and $av = a(c_1 b_1 + c_2 b_2 + c_3 b_3) = ac_1 b_1 + ac_2 b_2 + ac_3 b_3 \in S$.

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly finished.  Call the three matrices in your "basis" $X, Y$, and $Z$ and note that any linear combination of these matrices will be an element of $S$.  Then, given any $A \in S$, we can write $A = xX + yY + zZ$ for some $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$.  Given another matrix, say $B \in S$, then $B = x'X + y'Y + z'Z$ for some $x', y', z' \in \mathbb{R}$.  Adding $A$ and $B$, it is easy to see that the result will also be in $S$:

$$A + B = xX + yY + zZ + x'X + y'Y + z'Z = (x + x')X + (y + y')Y + (z + z')Z$$

Since we again have a linear combination of $X, Y$, and $Z$.  Thus, $S$ is closed under addition.  If we want to take a scalar multiple of $A$, then that result is also in $S$:

$$cA = c(xX + yY + zZ) = cxX + cyY + czZ$$

Which is again a linear combination of the basis matrices, so $S$ is also closed under scalar multiplication.  From here, we have shown that $S$ satisfies every condition to be a subspace.

---

As Rebecca said, the approach seems clumsy.  The abundance of letters doesn't help either.